# Преобразование UNIX в время

Tags: python, python-3.x, unix, время

У меня есть 2 UNIX времени. Я хочу получить разницу между этим временем и превратить ее в дату (минутах и секундах) как это можно сделать?

Comment: время в timestamp? или что имеется ввиду под "2 UNIX времени"?

Comment: Просто вычесть и просто поделить на 60 с остатком?

Answer (score 3):

Можно совсем по простому не используя Питон-модулей:

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://tio.run/##PYzBDkAwEETv/Yq9SEioLbr04GtEwkEJ6@Dra4vYw2TyZna2i6fV1yEwQg@G0HUW5bTrWrKNYvNjVznSpqobS@oYB@Gz51QKBTBmapl9Di@PWpZA@IJEnJrWc89BSpJH/fJon3zb49rfej6zEG4)

```
t0 = 1609850000.987654
t1 = 1609859296.123456
sec = int(t1 - t0)
min, sec = sec // 60, sec % 60
hour, min = min // 60, min % 60
print(hour, min, sec)
```

Вывод:

```
2 34 55
```

---

Пример как это сделать с форматированием, используя только [time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) модуль (внимание, разница выше 24 часов будет выведена не верно (а по модулю 24 часов)):

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://tio.run/##XVCxDoIwEN37FbeQUsWmKFRL4ubg4qSbMcZIURJpSXsOfj0WUQbf9O7uvXuXa194t2bRdaWu4FA3eqMfeDnYPbrY66s1pU9gkoCzT1OeYQ2SFQQC6qa1DgGD5VP7MOsL7tFVPYlptC2iXRHtaTJMbs2n/13L2Nc3XUPQclVRiIacnwRmUBscDb8rGDumxYm7kFS3MRWUjZzTYavT@HQGPCEowmGpFGqViwCuVkuZZwTTsa3mSvJ0vshySVrXB/79IWhngIKxrnsD)

```
def TimeDeltaToStr(seconds, *, round_ = 6):
    import time
    s = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(seconds))
    s += ('%.9f' % round(seconds - int(seconds), round_))[1:].rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
    return s

t0 = 1609850000.987654
t1 = 1609859296.123456
print(TimeDeltaToStr(t1 - t0))
```

Вывод:

```
02:34:55.135802
```

---

Если надо получить используя `time` модуль сами численные значения минут и секунд, а не строку отформатированного времени то делаем так (внимание, разница выше 24 часов будет выведена не верно (а по модулю 24 часов)):

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://tio.run/##PYtBDoMgFET3nOIvNWkJqKAsehYXjUEWHwiOi56eYho7m3l5mckf7CmOtQbOqYAQeBNQ9CJtlVuMapFuma2ZBPRfu8FZqYdxMlZ4NH39pOerurZ7ElQvcgkRnYcEr3s6y4N@zCHeeGzvvtYv)

```
import time
t0 = 1609850000.987654
t1 = 1609859296.123456
gt = time.gmtime(t1 - t0)
print(gt.tm_hour, gt.tm_min, gt.tm_sec)
```

Вывод:

```
2 34 55
```

---

Если надо не разницу секунд отформатировать а сам штамп Unix времени то делаем так:

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://tio.run/##XVDLCsIwELz3K/YS0mgNVm2wBU8iePFkPYiIiG1tDmlCuh78@prUJ@5php3ZGdbcsdbNtOuKsoKV0Zc6l6rM9RZtiA61eFYmgkEEVt@a4gQLECwLwI1URlsEr@p563ae8BZt5UFIyZ4TxUkBZJ2RTUa2NHpKrqoXfBIYe50YLsDZeFpRIM/IrwhGIBv8Mb1LMXaIsyO3LliakI4p@2BOfy5T2OVL2nNb4s020AYButqxGKfzJJ2kgseT6SwRgbE@6v8hjHXdAw)

```
def EpochTimeToStr(timestamp, *, round_ = 6):
    import time
    s = time.strftime('%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(timestamp))
    s += ('%.9f' % round(timestamp - int(timestamp), round_))[1:].rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
    s += ' UTC'
    return s

t = 1609859296.123456
print(EpochTimeToStr(t))
```

Вывод:

```
2021.01.05 15:08:16.123456 UTC
```